# certificate has expired with nodejs

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, certificate

I have a `bigbluebutton` meeting url. I access via postman and browser without any problem and I get the success code. But when I send HTTPS `get` request to the URL in my nodejs project, I get certificate has expired error. What can be the problem?

```
let createApiUrl = `https://bbb.example.com/bigbluebutton/api/create?name=${meetingName}&logoutURL=${logoutUri}&record=true&meetingID=${meetingId}&attendeePW=${attendeePW}&moderatorPW=${moderatorPW}&checksum=${checkSum}`;
response = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  return HTTP.call("GET", `${createApiUrl}`, {}, (error, response) => {
    if (error) {
      reject(error);
    } else {
      resolve(response);
    }
  });
});
```

Error message:

```
 - Error: certificate has expired
 - at TLSSocket.<anonymous>
 - at emitNone
 - at TLSSocket.emit
 - at TLSSocket._finishInit
 - at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone code: 'CERT_HAS_EXPIRED' }
```

Comment: Looks like the cert is expired?

Comment: I don't understand your question, the certification expired so what do you need help with ? If you're asking for how to fix this you could've said so because it's really unclear

Comment: If the server is using a LetsEncrypt certificate (I can't check because you concealed it) and your nodejs is using an older truststore aka cacerts that doesn't have the ISRG root cert _or_ an older OpenSSL library that doesn't substitute a shorter local path _and_ the server uses the 'long' chain bridging to DST root (all of which you also concealed) you are like many others affected because the DST root cert expired today, as covered by numerous other Qs in the last few hours. Browser(s) and postman validate okay because they use different truststores and code.